# How do I view a map location's info by long clicking in a custom activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have an activity that extends MapActivty that renders out a marker.  I would like the map to handle long clicks the same way the native Maps app does in finding the physical address of the geo point, displaying the address, then allow me to press the caption containing the address to view more details ie driving directions, what's nearby.

Is this possible or is the functionality embedded into the native Maps app?

BTW: because I need a custom options menu I am unable to implicitly launch the map activity with a geo:0,0?q=address string.

Comment: Are you saying it should only do this when you long press on a marker, or on an arbitrary point on the map?

Comment: Either or.  If I can get it working for both I can manually handle all events that aren't on the marker to prevent the directions from being shown.